# Color change at certain time vb.net

Tags: vb.net

This should be fairly straight forward but I cannot figure it out,

I have a button on a form with the default back colour of silver, when the button is pushed it turns red,

If the backcolor is red and it reaches a certain time of the day I want the backcolor to change to black. The code I have used is as follows

```
If CAButton.BackColor = Color.Red And DateTime.Now > #11:48:00# Then
        CAButton.BackColor = Color.Black
```

However for some reason now, it doesnt matter what time it is, as soon as I push the button it automatically changes to black, theres obviously something missing from the code but I cant tell what, can anyone see whats wrong?

Comment: If the button is clicked after the certain time, should it immediately turn black? Do you want the button's background colour to change back to red if it gets to the next day?

Comment: Hi @AndrewMorton the idea behind this is that if it reaches 7PM and the button is still Red I would like it to change to black without any input from the user

Comment: If you want it to change to Black automatically, without a user click required, then you'd need to setup a mechanism to determine either the current time or to trigger at the specified time.  This can be done with a timer that polls the current time periodically, or by computing the time duration to the target time and setting up either a timer with that interval or by putting a task/thread to sleep for that duration.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Mary's answer, you can check just the `TimeOfDay` from `DateTime.Now` against a `TimeSpan`:

```
Private targetTime As New TimeSpan(11, 48, 0)

Private Sub CAButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CAButton.Click
    If CAButton.BackColor = Color.Red And DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= targetTime Then
        CAButton.BackColor = Color.Black
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`Now` is the complete date with time. You need to compare it to a complete date with time.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Button1.BackColor = Color.Red And DateTime.Now > New DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day, 11, 48, 0) Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Black
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
I think the code would be better in a Timer.Tick event so it will happen automatically. Set the interval to one minute. I think that is 60000 milliseconds. The AndAlso short-circuits the If. If the first condition is false it doesn't check the second condition.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If Button1.BackColor = Color.Red AndAlso DateTime.Now > New DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day, 11, 48, 0) Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf Button1.BackColor = Color.Red AndAlso DateTime.Now < New DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day, 11, 48, 0) Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Red
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mary, this sort of works where if I click the button before 11:48 its red and after 11:48 its black however if it reaches 11:48 and the button is red it wont change to black which is what I am trying to achieve, any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I honestly thought this would have been a much simpler solution, I already have a timer.tick event set for this user so I am going to try and integrate the two as I also wanted it pause the timer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer) which is set to fire at the desired time, which you can set at the time the button is clicked.

I put a button named CAButton on a new form in a new Windows Forms project with this code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private caBlackTime As New TimeSpan(19, 0, 0)
    Private tim As Timer = Nothing

    Private Sub Tim_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        tim.Stop()
        If CAButton.BackColor = Color.Red Then
            CAButton.BackColor = Color.Black
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub CAButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CAButton.Click
        If tim IsNot Nothing Then tim.Dispose()

        Dim timeUntilChangeColour = caBlackTime - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay

        If timeUntilChangeColour > TimeSpan.Zero Then
            CAButton.BackColor = Color.Red
            tim = New Timer With {.Interval = CInt(timeUntilChangeColour.TotalMilliseconds)}
            AddHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf Tim_Tick
            tim.Start()

        Else
            CAButton.BackColor = Color.Black

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        ' Tidy up
        If tim IsNot Nothing Then tim.Dispose()

    End Sub

End Class
```

---

There are several sorts of Timer available, but this one is the Windows.Forms.Timer, which is the most suitable in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, @AndrewMorton beat me to it! Well I'm not going to let all this code go to waste...

Here is a solution which sets the color then sets it back automatically, without any button click, at specified intervals daily. Yes, daily - if the application is left open then it will happen tomorrow, and the next day, etc. The colors and time of day of each color are configurable. It also handles the case when the time has already passed when the user starts the application, and the case when the user starts the application between red and black. I use `System.Threading.Timer` here. Note: the accuracy of using any timer in .NET *may* drift over time.

```vb
' declare the timers, will be initialized in Form_Load
Private turnColor1Timer As System.Threading.Timer
Private turnColor2Timer As System.Threading.Timer
' set the two colors at this level for a single point of configuration
Private ReadOnly color1 As Color = Color.Red
Private ReadOnly color2 As Color = Color.Black
' first color time is set here for ease of configuration
Private ReadOnly color1TimeOfDay As New TimeSpan(11, 48, 0)
' second color time is set here based on previous color + some timespan, for ease of configuration
Private ReadOnly color2TimeOfDay As New TimeSpan(color1TimeOfDay.Add(New TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)).Ticks)
```

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' not sure if you want initial state to be black?
    turnColorTimerTick(color2)
    ' initialize the times to change colors to today
    Dim turnColor1Time = DateTime.Now.Date.Add(color1TimeOfDay)
    Dim turnColor2Time = DateTime.Now.Date.Add(color2TimeOfDay)
    ' check if that time has already passed today, if so set to tomorrow and change color
    If turnColor1Time.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) < 0 Then
        turnColorTimerTick(color1)
        turnColor1Time = turnColor1Time.AddDays(1)
    End If
    If turnColor2Time.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) < 0 Then
        turnColorTimerTick(color2)
        turnColor2Time = turnColor2Time.AddDays(1)
    End If
    ' initialize both timers to their appropriate times
    turnColor1Timer = New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf turnColorTimerTick, color1, CInt(turnColor1Time.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds), CInt(TimeSpan.FromDays(1).TotalMilliseconds))
    turnColor2Timer = New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf turnColorTimerTick, color2, CInt(turnColor2Time.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds), CInt(TimeSpan.FromDays(1).TotalMilliseconds))
End Sub

Private Sub turnColorTimerTick(state As Object)
    ' since it ticks in a background thread, must check if you need to invoke back to UI and call Invoke as needed
    If CAButton.InvokeRequired Then
        CAButton.Invoke(New Action(Of Object)(AddressOf turnColorTimerTick), {state})
    Else
        ' get color from argument passed
        Dim color = DirectCast(state, Color)
        CAButton.BackColor = color
    End If
End Sub
```

```vb
' this is put here because the timers should be disposed of
' if you choose to do this, you must remove Dispose from Form.Designer code
' (compiler error will alert you of this if you don't)
' of course, you could just modify the Dispose in Form.Designer,
' but I like to keep any code I have modified in the Form code instead
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing Then
            components?.Dispose()
        End If
        turnColor1Timer?.Dispose()
        turnColor2Timer?.Dispose()
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub
```